# How to destroy has_many associations plus join table records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have these models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :projects, :through => :jobs
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :people, :through => :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
end
```

When I delete a `person`, I want to delete all the associated `jobs` and `projects`. So I do something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :projects, :through => :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This works great to get rid of the `jobs` but leaves the `projects` (I'm assuming because without the `jobs`, the `person` has no way to reference the `project`). Is there an idiomatic way to do this or do I just need to use a `before_destroy` callback on my `jobs` to remove the `projects`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but try:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

What I think could be happening is that when you destroy a Person, Rails could be deleting your jobs records, then in the next "line" it tries to search projects, but since there are no jobs projects are not destroyed.

Comment: Awesome. That's it. I've been trying to fix this for hours. Thanks a lot.